# How to wait for an event in a async Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, stripe-payments

I would like to know how to wait for a particular event in one of my async methods. I would love to have hints about the event-system in modern EF-Core Framework and possible side-effects, that might occure in my use-case. The use-case description comes.

I have a combination of an Angular Application as a client-side and a .net EF-Core 2.2 Application as a server-side. I am trying to integrate stripe into my project. I would also like to handle all of the payment-work on the server-side.

At this very moment, when a user tries to alter his current subscription to one of my products, the client issues a Post-Request to my server. After that the server issues a request towards the stripe. This request to stripe returns some kind of a stripe-object, which I store in order to process upcoming events. Right at this moment my server-request finishes and there is no way to respond to client the needed information, e.g. if the wanted request finished well, or there was some kind of an error. Meanwhile, the stripe on it's side does some work. When it finishes, it informs my server via webhook, that certain event occured. I am processing this event on the server side and everything is perfect, except a single thing: my client knows nothing about the stripe-event that my server processes.

My idea to handle this problem would be to wait in the initial request, that was issued by client, until my web-hook is triggered, preferably with a timeout of, lets say, 10 seconds. Any suggestions?

Comment: read up on SignalR.

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to create a `TaskCompletionSource`, and register an event handler to complete it, then await its `Task`.

```
var source = new TaskCompletionSource<(object, EventArgs)>();  //Change the EventArgs type to the actual event args type that the event passes.

EVENT_YOU_WISH_TO_WAIT_FOR += (s, e) => source.TrySetResult((s, e));

async void timeout()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);  //10 secs
    source.TrySetException(new TaskCanceledException());
}

timeout();

try
{
    var (sender, @event) = await source.Task;

    //Statements here would be executed on the event is raised.
    //Do things with sender and @event provided.
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    //Handle timeout.
}
```